# Replacing Awkwardly Cut Drywall

Tags: drywall, walls

I recently had a scare with my plumbing where the plumbers had to cut a large hole behind my sink. I attached a picture of the hole below. It is around two feet tall by a foot and a half wide.

[image]

I have never replaced a piece of drywall so large, but from what I have seen online you are supposed to cut out a piece of drywall that matches the size, and put a wood brace behind so that you can nail the drywall into place; however, how am I supposed to do that in this case as the only thing that could be used to secure it on the bottom would be to drive the nail through the floor molding? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Make the hole bigger and cleaner, the sides must be cut halfway over a studs. For the top you can cut a 1x2 or or scrap lumber and screw it in under the lip to give you something to attach to.

Comment: Why didn't the plumber fix it?

Comment: Because it was paid for by my home warranty and they refuse to pay for pretty much anything

Answer (score 1):

Cut 3/4 inches over each stud. (Oscillating multitool is the best for this, but patience and a utility knife will suffice.)

Screw new drywall on. You could use a thin bit of plywood at the top horizontal seam to stiffen it up. Screw the old drywall as well. (Be careful about the power wires.) Tape and skim the seams. Caulk the joint between the baseboard and drywall. (Texture? I can't tell from the pic.) Paint.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your question is how to handle the bottom edge where there's no backing. I would cut a piece of lumber that fits in the opening and press it down tight to the bottom wall plate. Use construction adhesive or long screws to fasten to the bottom wall plate. Now run screws through the drywall at the ends to help support the top edge. This will be plenty strong.

One other thing you might do is to cut the drywall out behind the base trim down to the bottom plate. Then you can slide your patch piece down behind the base trim and not have to worry about taping right there.

As to the rest of it, I wouldn't bother cutting out to a stud unless it's convenient. Doing so makes for a more difficult cut, and you often hit screws along the way.. I would cut a new piece of drywall that completely covers the opening, Trace that on the wall, and cut on the trace line. Then float 3/4" x 3" backing on the sides and top. If you thoroughly screw both sides of the joint all the way around and then tape it, it'll be rock-solid.